# CSS - How to adjust height of div based on content?

Tags: html, css, height

I have a problem with the height of a div box.
I want the height of the div box to be 100% if the height of the text is smaller than the screen height, like height=100%
If the text is larger than the screen the div height should auto adjust, like height=auto
How to write CSS for a div achieve both ?

Comment: post code with snippet

Comment: what's wrong with `min-height:100%` - based on your requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS should be:

```
div.big { min-height: 100vh; }
```

and

```
<div class="big">  xxx </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Actually it's easy, my brain just had one dropout.